# CSS Animation Not Working As Expected With Image element In Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

*Below is a minimum mockup of a bug that I'm experiencing in Safari.*

---

**Expected behaviour:** The code is supposed to display a placeholder while another image loads and then fade-in that image while removing the placeholder.

```
placeholder -> fading in loaded image
```

**Actual behaviour:**
Works as expected in Chrome and Mozilla but ***fails in Safari***, resulting in the following effect:

```
placeholder -> white screen -> loaded image
```

Can somebody help me figure out why this is happening in Safari please? *(try running below example in chrome or mozilla vs safari to see for your self.)*

```js
const image = new Image();

image.onload = () => {
  document.getElementById('placeholder').remove();

  const el = document.createElement('img');
  el.setAttribute('src', 'http://deelay.me/1000/https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/03/19/38/board-361516_1280.jpg');
  el.setAttribute('width', '150');
  el.setAttribute('height', '150');

  el.style = `
    animation-name: testAnimation;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    background: red;
  `;

  document.body.appendChild(el);
}

image.src = 'http://deelay.me/1000/https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/03/19/38/board-361516_1280.jpg';
```

```css
#placeholder {
  background: #eee;
}

@-webkit-keyframes testAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="placeholder" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg' width%3D'200' height%3D'300' viewBox%3D'0 0 200 300'%2F%3E" width="150" height="150">
```

**(**

Another weird behaviour is that if `animation-duration` gets increased to around 3-4 seconds then the image does fade-in but the white screen is still there, i.e.

```
placeholder -> white screen -> fading in loaded image
```

**)**

### **update:**

After playing around with img’s background color it seems like in Safari the animation begins taking effect around 1s before the image even begins getting rendered to the screen.

- hence the white flick if the real image doesn't have a background color like the placeholder image does and hence why after adding a background color to the real image that background color becomes visible around 1 sec earlier before the image even starts displaying
- and hence the fade effect starting to take place around 1 sec earlier before the image even starts displaying

Whereas in Chrome and Mozilla the animation appears to be perfectly in sync with the image.

Run updated code to see for yourself

***(it also only seems to happen with `<img>`, I've tested it with some other elements (still inside of image.onload) and they work as expected.)***

### **update 2: See the fix in the answer below together with an explanation**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed by adding another `onload` event this time on the ***image element*** rather than on the explicit ***Image object*** and putting the `image.onload` listener inside of it.

Which seems to suggest that in Safari, animation and styles are applied as soon as the `<img>` is added to the DOM - before it is fully loaded (its `onload` event called.)

- This can be tested by giving the `<img>` a background color and seeing it show up together with the animation as soon as the element is added to the DOM and seeing that it takes an extra second until the image itself becomes visible
- You can also see the same effect happen without using any animation at all just by giving the `<img>` a background color

***(a bug in Safari?*** *My Safari version: Version 11.0.2 (13604.4.7.1.3))*

**Edit:** Actually the problem seems to be caused by caching, Safari doesn't seem to cache the pre-loaded proxied image while other browsers do cache it. Safari seems to fire another request for that image when it gets rendered to the screen - hence the styles being visible prior to seeing the actual image since the image is still being downloaded.

**Edit 2: Upon further investigation it seems like Safari is actually the only one out of those 3 browsers that is behaving as expected - this is because the image's HTTP response contains a `Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate` header explicitly instructing the browser to not cache the image.**

```js
const image = new Image();
    
const el = document.createElement('img');
el.setAttribute('src', 'http://deelay.me/500/https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/03/19/38/board-361516_1280.jpg');
el.setAttribute('width', '150');
el.setAttribute('height', '150');
el.style = `
  animation-name: testAnimation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  background-color: red;
`;
    
el.onload = () => {
  image.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById('placeholder').remove();
    document.body.appendChild(el);
  }
}

image.src = 'http://deelay.me/500/https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/03/19/38/board-361516_1280.jpg';
```

```css
#placeholder {
  background: #eee;
}

@-webkit-keyframes testAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="placeholder" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg' width%3D'200' height%3D'300' viewBox%3D'0 0 200 300'%2F%3E" width="150" height="150">
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be related to the specific server/image you are using. I tried changing just the image URL (to something on wikimedia.org, just for testing purposes), and the animation began working as expected in Safari 11.0.2 (13604.4.7.1.6).

Pre-loading the image may help... or even better (all of this assuming you have proper usage rights, of course), you can try copying the image to your web server so it can be loaded locally. Essentially, you're just remedying the fact that Safari has finished running the animation by the time it can load the image from the remote server. You could also try using window.onload instead of image.onload, to force all external resources to be loaded before it runs.

Comment: I don't think it's related to specific image because It only happens in Safari. Also image.onload only fires when the image is done loading - that's when I'm adding the image to the page and giving it animation

Comment: I understand what it's _supposed_ to do, but since that is not what's happening, a little troubleshooting is in order. You may want to at least try these suggestions, because at the very least, it will provide some clues about what is going on. Here is a fiddle with your original code, which works perfectly using a different image: https://jsfiddle.net/Lb81qjjb/1/

Comment: But you removed the placeholder image which needs to be there

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to include the html you posted. Animation still works in the revised fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lb81qjjb/6/

Comment: it works on chrome and mozilla but still doesn't work on safari

Comment: I am currently running that fiddle in Safari, and it appears to be working correctly. Perhaps you are using an older version of Safari? I'm running 11.0.2 (13604.4.7.1.6) on High Sierra 10.13.2.

Comment: My safari version: Version 11.0.2 (13604.4.7.1.3),  OS version: 10.13.2

Comment: Try running it a couple of times you should see red bg flickering in in-between the placeholder and the real image

Comment: I apologize; I was unable to reproduce your issue when using a different image, and then got pulled away. As I mentioned above, it had to do with the order of execution... so forcing images to load before execution, as I had suggested, was exactly what was needed. Glad you've got it sorted.

Comment: Part1: Sorry I still don't understand your second paragraph I think you're misunderstanding the original example, the original example doesn't just instantly render an image element and fires its animation waiting for the image to be downloaded -- it instead programatically downloads that image and only displays it once its onload event has executed, i.e. after it has been downloaded and already exists.

Comment: Part2: So there's no waiting for the network request before displaying the image, the image element is created and displayed only once the image has been successfully downloaded -- and this works just fine in other browsers it's only Safari that is acting up by requiring another `onload` event this time on the image element rather than on the Image object

Comment: We're just saying the same thing in different ways. Other browsers are running the animation only after the image is loaded and ready to use. Safari is not.

I mentioned some things to try:

1. preload an image - e.g., [link](https://www.thonky.com/javascript-and-css-guide/javascript-image-preload)
2. copy the image to your own web server - wherever you're running your code from, save and load the image from there, too, to reduce network lag
3. use 'onload' on a containing element (I'd used 'window' as an example) to force Safari to finish loading the image before running the animation.

Comment: So the bottom line is, your solution of putting the image inside of a containing element and using onload on the element is the same idea as #3 above. #3 is just a restatement of that second paragraph, where I mentioned using window.onload instead of image.onload as a way to help troubleshoot the problem. 'window' is just a containing element for 'image'. Does that make more sense?

Comment: But the image is already being pre-loaded in my code? Anyway it actually seems like the core problem might not be with styles being applied before image is visible, but because Safari doesn't seem to use the pre-loaded version while other browsers are -- it instead fires another request for that image once element is added to the DOM (seems like it doesn't cache it?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164132/discussion-between-criminally-inane-and-linasmnew).